# How to Get Value from Array to Variable Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Questions
I want to move Value in array to Variable
ex.
[1,2,3] = array
i want to get "1" to Variable
Var = 1 <= Which "1" is Value in array

My code :

```
//Loop For Seach Value

for result in 0...DataSearch.count-1 {
    let Object = DataSearch[result] as! [String:AnyObject];

self.IDMachine_Array.append(Object["IDMac"] as! String!);
self.Password_Array.append(Object["password"] as! String!);
self.Conpassword_Array.append(Object["password_con"] as! String!);
self.Tel_Array.append(Object["Tel"] as! String!);
self.Email_Array.append(Object["Email"] as! String!);
self.Email = String(self.Email_Array);
}
```

I try Value Email = Email_Array
Result print :

```
[xxxx@xxxx.com]
```

but i want Result is :

```
xxxx@xxxx.com -> without []
```

Please Help me please.
Thank you.
Sorry if my solution is wrong.

Comment: I would get rid of all those forced casts and properly test each one. If something ever goes wrong with any of them you'll have a nasty runtime crash that will be difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the first element from the array?

```
self.Email = self.EmailArray.first!
```

(this is the same as `self.Email = self.EmailArray[0]`)

NB: `first!` or `[0]` will both crash if the array is empty. The original question uses `as!` so obviously just need this to work. However, if you wanted safety you would use something like

```
if let email as self.EmailArray.first {
    self.Email = email
}
```

or

```
self.Email = self.EmailArray.first ?? "no email found"
```

Comment: yes i want to get first element in array,I will try now.

Comment: FYI - Of course this will crash if the array is empty.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep - and this code would fail peer review anywhere I worked :) However, the question contains `as!` on pretty much every line, so I've assumed that the op is looking for a quick fix. I'll add that warning anyway just so anyone else looking at the answer is warned :)